# Where is the line responsible for jpeg compression level for the product page?

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.4, overrides

I'm looking to turn off compression for product pages specifically, meaning if I uploaded a 200k jpeg file, I expect to see exactly the same 200k file on a product page.

Looking to find a line that governs said compression. Looked into other similar questions but the answers didn't work for me at all.

Magento generates a lot of jpegs based on that original 200k one, but I'm looking to completely bypass those cached images and display the original one instead.

Comment: Magento version 2.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Image size options are configured in the theme's `/etc/view.xml` file. I believe that image compression is handled by [Fastly image optimization](https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/cdn/fastly-image-optimization.html).

[This fine answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/233196/how-does-magento-2-process-compress-product-images) describes the benefits of overriding the `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php` and `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image/ParamsBuilder.php` files for improved images in Magento 2.

Comment: Not sure it's exactly what I was looking for. Setting compression level to 100 will simply make the images larger than the originals, what I need to do is bypass the compression algorithm (for just the product page) entirely and output images exactly as they were uploaded - their md5 hashes (for example) would be the same.

Comment: @ЗахарJoe Yes, I worded my answer carefully to emphasize that this is not the exact answer you asked for, but it is an answer that addresses the problem.

Comment: It doesn't quite address the problem, because you either end up with images that look bad and are small, or images that look *almost* as good and way larger than the originals. I understand Magento's logic there, if you upload original, say, TIFF or PNG files then it makes sense to convert them to JPEGs with a certain compression level. Trouble is, our images were already JPEG compressed for production and we lost the uncompressed originals.